# jQuery each function throwing error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a custom step.js application for my project. I'm getting error on object scope. Below is my code

```
var STEPPED = {
    el: {
        stepContentDiv: $('#stepContent'),
        stepNavDiv:     $('#stepNav'),
        stepNavLi:      $('#stepNav li'),
        stepNavAnchor:  $('#stepNav li a'),
        stepNavDone:  $('#stepNav li a'),
        stepNavActive:  $('#stepNav li a')
    },
    doActive: function(){
        this.el.stepNavDone.on('click', function(){
            this.el.stepNavLi.each(function(){
                alert();
            });
        });
    },
    init: function(){
        this.doActive();
    }
}
STEPPED.init();
```

Getting error when I run this

```
this.el.stepNavLi.each(function(){
    alert();
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stepNavLi' of undefined

Can anyone pleas help me what is the issue here? Thanks in advance

Comment: your code can't find this.el, that is undefined...

Comment: yes this is my question that why its undefined. But its defined at the top. cant understand

Answer (score 1):

Within the `click` event handler function, `this` refers to the element that was clicked on, not the `STEPPED` object. You need to cache the reference to the object in a variable if you want to retain the reference to it within the click handler. Try this:

```
doActive: function() {
    var _stepped = this;
    _stepped.el.stepNavDone.on('click', function(){
        _stepped.el.stepNavLi.each(function(){
            alert();
        });
    });
},
```